# Oracle VARCHAR limit as a procedure out parameter

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure written under Oracle 11g and one of my out parameters is a string (i.e. of type `VARCHAR`).

I use this parameter to return a concatenated list of numbers separated by `;`.
This list can be of any size and I do not know the size in advance.

My question is does `VARCHAR` will be enough or does it have a size limit (which will cause me troubles of course). If not what should I use for this case ?

Thanks

Comment: Seems to me that `VARCHAR` is limited by 50 chars

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you use a suitable datatype like array of number instead of trying to encode a complex structure in a string?

Answer (score 7):

A VARCHAR2 in PL/SQL may contain 32,767 characters.   (Note that this is different to a VARCHAR2 column on the database, which has a maximum length of 4,000 characters)

Also, you say above that you're using VARCHAR.  Oracle recommends that you use VARCHAR2, not VARCHAR.

Comment: So is there a way to use a type with no limit ? or how should I return a string which is built dynamically by the procedure and might pass the size limit ?

Comment: If 32,767 isn't enough, I'd suggest taking a look at the CLOB datatype.  It's more difficult to work with, but it can be up to at least 2Gb (don't remember the exact limit)

Comment: Be aware that the limits are 4000 or 32767 *bytes* and not characters. The difference is important if you use a multi-byte character encoding scheme.

Comment: It can be characters if you have your DB set to char "mode" rather than byte "mode".  See http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/character-semantics-and-globalization-9i.php for a better explanation.

Comment: cagcowboy: Are you sure? AFAIK, the NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS setting only affects the default interpretation when declaring the length of a VARCHAR2 column without a BYTE/CHAR qualifier. It has no effect on the actual type limits.